# Where can we find the details of what our commitment is to this new site?

Tags: bug

Now that the site has moved past the commitment phase, I can't find a description of exactly what it was I committed to (e.g. minimum number of answers etc.).

Where is this information?

Comment: technically nothing I'm pretty sure? See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55048/997587 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55048/997587, though I could very well be wrong.

Comment: @starball, I'm not trying to get out of it; I'm simply trying to find out what it was. While the site was soliciting for commitments, the details were right there, but now the fine print has disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Good to see you here Ray!

## Criteria for fulfilling commitment

Nothing happens if you don't "fulfill your commitment", but if you do want to be recorded as having [fulfilled your commitment](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32363/190792):

> "The code checks that you get 10 points to fulfill your commitment. Each question and answer gives you 1 point. Receiving the Beta badge gives you an extra 3 points. So really, users who join in the private beta need only make 7 posts to fulfill their commitment so long as they meet the other criteria for that badge, while users who join in the public beta need to make the full 10 posts."

## What it says when you click "commit" in Area 51

What it says when you click "commit" is slightly less compact compared to the full algorithm that's spelled out in the above quote. It just says that you commit to posting at least 10 times [during the first 180 days].

## Rewards for fulfilling commitment

If you fulfill your commitment (i.e. acquire 10 points) within the first 180 days of the site's beta, you'll get 50 points on Area 51 and the person who referred you will also get 25 points on Area 51:

[image]

Your Area 51 profile will also say that you fulfilled your commitment, as follows:

[image]

There's also some Area 51 [badges related to commitment](https://area51.stackexchange.com/badges).

## Final remarks

Not a lot of people look at Area 51, so the above rewards for fulfilling your commitment might not be very significant to you. The requirements for the [beta badge](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23/5) are similar but much less demanding, and the badge is actually on this site rather than on Area 51.